# Multiple plots, every plot with same X but different Y values. I want the line for each plot to start when the Y values have a positive value

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I have to plot many plots in the same graph. The x values is the same array for all and it is an array from 0 to N. The Y values for each plot are arrays that start with 0 and start having positive values at different x, depending on the plot.
EXAMPLE:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y1 = [0, 0, 10, 12 , 53, ... , n]
y2 = [0, 0, 0, 12 , 53, ... , n]
y3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 67, 53, ... , n]
```

when I plot there is a vertical line that goes from the bottom to the first positive value for Y. In the case of y1, there is line from (1, 0) to (2, 10) that is the line i want to avoid and just plot from (2, 10).

I know I can create new arrays for x and y to match the conditions I want, but I really need to know if there is other way.

There is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvBp.png) with one example of my current plot.
[Link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHcfW.png)

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This is a excel where a user types a number, this number will be the number 
of months.
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('INPUT.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_name('ASSUMPTIONS')
Num_Meses = np.array([i for i in range(int(sheet1.cell(5, 5).value) + 1)])


# Then I create a dictonary from which I take the arrays, (YPP, Y1P, Y2P) 
are type 'numpy.ndarray'
filt = df['WELL TYPE'] == 'PP'
YPP = df.loc[filt, 'OIL PRODUCTION'][0]

filt = df['WELL TYPE'] == '1P'
Y1P = df.loc[filt, 'OIL PRODUCTION'][0] + YPP

filt = df['WELL TYPE'] == '2P'
Y2P = df.loc[filt, 'OIL PRODUCTION'][0] + Y1P

filt = df['WELL TYPE'] == '3P'
Y3P = df.loc[filt, 'OIL PRODUCTION'][0] + Y2P

plt.plot(Num_Meses, Y3P, label='3P')
plt.plot(Num_Meses, Y2P, label='2P')
plt.plot(Num_Meses, Y1P, label='1P')
plt.plot(Num_Meses, YPP, label='PP', color='k')
```

Comment: Hi Esteban, could you include your imports of packages in the code and include the variables you use (for instance `Num_Meses` is used at the end, but we don't know what it refers to)

Comment: You could replace the zero values with `NaN` to avoid them being plotted.